# Hiding the TouchId popup on SecItemUpdate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios8, touch-id

I have seen in some touchId apps where on `SecItemUpdate` the touchId UI screen never pops up and the update still happens. I need similar functionality for my app and based on what I have read from Apple Developer's guide (my understanding maybe wrong) have come up with some options but they don't seem to work. Here's what I have done so far. 
Setting `kSecUseNoAuthenticationUI` to `YES`, an error code `-25308` is returned. Setting `kSecUseNoAuthenticationUI` to `NO`, an error code `-50` is returned. If I don't include `kSecUseNoAuthenticationUI`, then the default authentication UI pops up.

```
NSDictionary *query = @{(__bridge id)kSecClass: (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                        (__bridge id)kSecAttrService: @"SampleService",
                        (__bridge id)kSecUseNoAuthenticationUI: @YES
                        };

NSDictionary *changes = @{
    (__bridge id)kSecValueData: [@"UPDATED_SECRET_PASSWORD_TEXT" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
    };

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    OSStatus status = SecItemUpdate((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)changes);
    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"SEC_ITEM_UPDATE_STATUS", nil), [self keychainErrorToString:status]];
    [super printResult:self.textView message:msg];
});]
```

So I am lost at this point. Appreciate if you can give me some pointers on how to disable this touchId UI popup on SecItemUpdate. Thanks

Comment: Were you able to perform an update without a TouchID prompt?

Comment: I was able to do the update without the prompt. I changed my secItemAdd to this '(__bridge id)kSecUseNoAuthenticationUI: @NO,
                   (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked' and this seems to have fixed it on update too. Initially it was set to `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly' which caused the prompt to popup during an update.

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at video WWDC 2014 Session 711, the `kSecUseNoAuthenticationUI` is mentioned around 31:35.

You can look also in "SecItem.h" :

```
 @constant kSecUseNoAuthenticationUI Specifies a dictionary key whose value
        is a CFBooleanRef. If provided with a value of kCFBooleanTrue, the error
        errSecInteractionNotAllowed will be returned if the item is attempting
        to authenticate with UI.
```

I'm not sure you can both disable the pop-up and perform an update.

What I suppose to understand : setting the `kSecUseNoAuthenticationUI` option will not display the pop-up. But if you 're trying to access to an item that requires an authentication, it will fail by indicating you that the item by returning a `errSecInteractionNotAllowed` as the operation result

Answer (score 1):

According to the iOS8 release notes, this supposed is the case and you should delete and re-add your item

```
if (status == errSecDuplicateItem) { // exists
      status = SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributes);

      if (status == errSecSuccess) {
        status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributes, nil);
      }
}
```

Comment: can you share a link to those release notes? I don't see anything about that [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1806?locale=en_US)